# php code in html not working even after enabling addhandler in .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have a little piece of php code in an html file but when i browse to the file it displays some part of the code instead of executing. below is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION["valid_user"])
  {
   // User not logged in, redirect to login page
    Header('Location: login.html?returnurl=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
   }
  echo "<p><a href=\"logout.html\">logout " . $_SESSION["valid_user"] . "</a></p>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
```

here is the content of .htaccess file

```
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`
```

php version: 5.4.4
server:  apache

It would be really helpful if someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `Addhandler` directive with this:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php .html
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (OS X Yosemite 10.10 running php5 and apache), When I created a .htaccess with any AddHandler, apache would throw a 500 misconfiguration error.

However, I did find that modifying my /etc/apache2/other/php5.conf worked perfectly.

```
Before:  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
After:   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```